# problem displaying images with browsers

Tags: asp.net, browser

I had bad problem I had table in database which display images for products the data type of model image VarBinary(Max) when I published new web site and tested the pages on sararie,firefox,IE8 the image in some of images appeared with small size from the original on image size and It appeared with very very small,So please what I can do?

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Do the images get `height` and `width` attributes?

Comment: <asp:Image ID="img1" Width="100%" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Id","Handlers/Model.ashx?Id={0}") %>' />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the width and height values should be in px, not in %, do manually and check.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Width/Height property in order to keep the original dimensions of the image.